# How to write PNG image to string with the PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have generated an image using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). How can I save it to a string in memory?
The `Image.save()` method requires a file.

I'd like to have several such images stored in dictionary.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You can use the [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) class to get a wrapper around strings that behaves like a file. The `BytesIO` object provides the same interface as a file, but saves the contents just in memory:

```
import io

with io.BytesIO() as output:
    image.save(output, format="GIF")
    contents = output.getvalue()
```

You have to explicitly specify the output format with the `format` parameter, otherwise PIL will raise an error when trying to automatically detect it.

If you loaded the image from a file it has a [`format`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.format) property that contains the original file format, so in this case you can use `format=image.format`.

In old Python 2 versions before introduction of the `io` module you would have used the [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module instead.

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I googled every combination of python, string, reader, writer, buffer and didn't come up with anything.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - saved me much head scratching this morning.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(    
I got this KeyError in Imaging/PIL/Image.pyc line 1423      
-> raise KeyError(ext) # unknown extension

Comment: @Radian, I actually have the same problem, any ideas?

Comment: @Radian, The PIL documentation on the save() method says: `You can use a file object instead of a filename. In this case, you must always specify the format.` So if the first argument is a file object, you have to pass in the second argument, which is the format (e.g. `'PNG'`).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28102870/307084) for additional information. To ```Image.open(theStringIObuffer)``` with ```PIL```, you may need to first do ```theStringIObuffer.seek(0)```.

Comment: In the current Python version, StringIO is in io package, you must write : `from io import StringIO`

Comment: you can better use `image.save(output, format=image.format)`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `BytesIO` in Python 3? Try doing `from io import BytesIO as StringIO` instead.

Comment: @Gustavo6046: Since the io module is also available in Python2 I edited the answer to just use `io.BytesIO` for all versions.

Answer (score 31):

For Python3 it is required to use BytesIO:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.new("RGB", (300, 50))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0, 0), "This text is drawn on image")

byte_io = BytesIO()

image.save(byte_io, 'PNG')
```

Read more: http://fadeit.dk/blog/post/python3-flask-pil-in-memory-image

Answer (score 26):

sth's solution didn't work for me
because in ...

> Imaging/PIL/Image.pyc line 1423 ->
>   raise KeyError(ext) # unknown
>   extension

It was trying to detect the format from the extension in the filename , which doesn't exist in StringIO case

You can bypass the format detection by setting the format yourself in a parameter

```
import StringIO
output = StringIO.StringIO()
format = 'PNG' # or 'JPEG' or whatever you want
image.save(output, format)
contents = output.getvalue()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 16):

`save()` can take a file-like object as well as a path, so you can use an in-memory buffer like a `StringIO`:

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
im.save(buf, format='JPEG')
jpeg = buf.getvalue()
```

Comment: Thank you. 
StringIO - thats what I need.

Comment: The save() interface is much cleaner than the tostring() interface when it comes to getting a PNG, JPEG, or actual file format.

Answer (score 15):

With modern (as of mid-2017 Python 3.5 and Pillow 4.0):

StringIO no longer seems to work as it used to. The BytesIO class is the proper way to handle this. Pillow's save function expects a string as the first argument, and surprisingly doesn't see StringIO as such. The following is similar to older StringIO solutions, but with BytesIO in its place.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("a_file.png")
faux_file = BytesIO()
image.save(faux_file, 'png')
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the, image_data = faux_file.getvalue() ?

Comment: @Ryan Good catch, no purpose at all. It was left over from testing and finally removed.

Answer (score 9):

When you say "I'd like to have number of such images stored in dictionary", it's not clear if this is an in-memory structure or not.

You don't need to do any of this to meek an image in memory.  Just keep the `image` object in your dictionary.

If you're going to write your dictionary to a file, you might want to look at  `im.tostring()` method and the `Image.fromstring()` function

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

> im.tostring() => string
>
> Returns a string containing pixel
>   data, using the standard "raw"
>   encoder.
>
> Image.fromstring(mode, size, data) =>
>   image
>
> Creates an image memory from pixel
>   data in a string, using the standard
>   "raw" decoder.

The "format" (.jpeg, .png, etc.) only matters on disk when you are exchanging the files.  If you're not exchanging files, format doesn't matter.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to retain the PNG format, not reduce it to raw pixel data.