# md5 from pil object

Tags: python, md5, python-imaging-library

how i can get md5 of the pil object without saving to file ?

```
    imq.save('out.png')
    hash =  hashlib.md5(open('out.png','rb').read()).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 17):

Actually there is simpler solution:

```
hashlib.md5(img.tostring()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Looks like .tostring() is deprecated as of 2.0 in favor of .tobytes()

Comment: In 2017 .tostring() is no longer supported, use .tobytes() instead

Answer (score 5):

Turning @Ignacio's answer into code, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string/646297#646297) to help:

```
import StringIO, hashlib

output = StringIO.StringIO()
img.save(output)
hash = hashlib.md5(output.getvalue()).hexdigest()
```

As the referenced other answer notes, this might lead to a KeyError if PIL tries to automatically detect the output format. To avoid this problem you can specify the format manually:

```
img.save(output, format='GIF')
```

(Note: I've used "img" as the variable, rather than your "imq" which I assumed was a typo.)

Comment: When I try to save to either a `StringIO` or `BytesIO` object I get a `KeyError` because the format cannot be inferred; providing a known format yields different errors.

Comment: @FluxIX avoid the KeyError with kwargs format='foo' (as you probably did). You'd have to describe the "different errors" for anyone to help with that.

Comment: I wasn't asking for help with the different errors, just specifying the parameter as a keyworded argument.

Comment: @FluxIX okay, I've included the warning that the referenced other answer provided, for clarity. I thought your "providing a known format yields different answers" meant the solution still didn't work for you even with that. (Now I don't know what to think... does this work for you or not?)

Comment: Specifying the parameter as a keyworded argument did work.

Answer (score 4):

You could write it to a `StringIO` instead, and then take the hash of that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following PIL `Image` class method to get the raw image data to feed to `md5()`.

> im.getdata() => sequence
>
> Returns the contents of an image as a
>   sequence object containing pixel
>   values. The sequence object is
>   flattened, so that values for line one
>   follow directly after the values of
>   line zero, and so on.

Note that the resulting MD5 hash of using this **won't** be the same as your sample code because it is (at least partially) independent of the particular image file format used to save the image. It could be useful if you wanted to compare actual images independent of the particular image file format they may be saved in.

To use it you would need to store the MD5 hash of the image data somewhere independent of any image file where it could be retrieved when needed -- as opposed to generating it by reading the entire file into memory as binary data like the code in your question does. Instead you would need to always load the image into PIL and then use the `getdata()` method on it to compute hashes.