# How do I resolve this error: TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not PngImageFile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-imaging-library, image-conversion

I used to use `Python 2.7` and `pygame` and, to load a PNG and `blit` it to a surface, this code was enough:

```
sprites = pygame.image.load('sprites.png')
background.blit(sprites, (0, 0), rect)
```

Now I'm using `Python 3`, which means I need to load `PIL` to deal with PNG files. My new code looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
sprites = Image.open('sprites.png')
background.blit(sprites, (0, 0), rect)
```

But when I run the new code, I get this error on the last line:

> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not PngImageFile

So the `sprites` variable is a `PngImageFile` and `background.blit()` is expecting a `pygame.Surface` object as input:

- Should I convert the `PngImageFile` to a `pygame.Surface`? I can't find any way to do this.
- Is there a better way to `blit` a PIL Image to a `pygame.Surface` object?

I've tried hard looking for an answer on StackOverflow, so I'm pretty sure this is not a duplicate question. Any comments or suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Sorry, but HOW did you get PIL to work with Python3.. They havn't even released it yet? o0

Comment: Also, load the image into a pygame image from a string: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.fromstring

Comment: There is a fork, called pillow, it seems to work, let me know if you need further details

Answer (score 2):

```
from PIL import Image
sprites = Image.open('sprites.png')
pygameImage = pygame.image.fromstring(str(buffer(sprites)), win.size, 'RGB', False)
background.blit(pygameImage, (0, 0), rect)
```

Since i'm running Python3 without any luck on PIL i'm not entirely sure this will work out of the box. Because you need to get the text-representation of the `sprites` object instead of the array of data.

Following might help you to convert a PIL object into a string?

- [Python PIL: how to write PNG image to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string)
- http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.fromstring - Pygames fromstring function.

Or simply try:

```
from PIL import Image
sprites = pygame.image.load(Image.open('sprites.png'))
background.blit(sprites, (0, 0), rect)
```

Comment: The third line, slightly modified, at the moment is like this:

    pygameImage = pygame.image.fromstring(sprites.tostring(), len(sprites.tostring()), 'RGB', False)

But I get this:

TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not int

Any idea?

Comment: @hertsmael Probably because `size=...` (if you read the docs on `pygame.image.fromstring` requires width+height, not the length of the string that represents the image). Try doing `pygameImage = pygame.image.fromstring(sprites.tostring(), (sprites.width, sprites.height), 'RGB', False)` instead.

Comment: As I could't find the right methods in PngImageFile object to get width and height I juust set them hardcoded (just to try making it work).
The error I get is:

pygameImage = pygame.image.fromstring(sprites.tostring(), (760, 166), 'RGB', False)

ValueError: String length does not equal format and resolution size
http://pastebin.com/QpuEwPc0