# python PIL image how to save image to a buffer so can be used later?

Tags: python, io, gridfs, stringio

I have a `png` file which should be convert to `jpg` and save to `gridfs` , I use python's `PIL` lib to load the file and do the converting job, the problem is I want to store the converted image to a MongoDB Gridfs, in the saving procedure, I can't just use the `im.save()` method. so I use a `StringIO` to hold the temp file but it don't work.

here is the code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image
from pymongo import MongoClient
import gridfs
from StringIO import StringIO


im = Image.open("test.png").convert("RGB")

#this is what I tried, define a 
#fake_file with StringIO that stored the image temporarily.
fake_file = StringIO()
im.save(fake_file,"jpeg")

fs = gridfs.GridFS(MongoClient("localhost").stroage)

with fs.new_file(filename="test.png") as fp:
    # this will not work
    fp.write(fake_file.read())


# vim:ai:et:sts=4:sw=4:
```

I am very verdant in python's `IO` mechanism, How to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`getvalue` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO.getvalue) instead of `read`:

```
with fs.new_file(filename="test.png") as fp:
    fp.write(fake_file.getvalue())
```

Alternatively, you could use [`read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) if you first [`seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to read from the beginning of the StringIO.

```
with fs.new_file(filename="test.png") as fp:
    fake_file.seek(0)
    fp.write(fake_file.read())
```

Comment: thanks, That works, but why I should `seek(0)` first to get `read()` work? it's confusing and weird.

Comment: And I don't find any specification about the `StringIO.read()` method in the [official document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) where can I learn more about  the behavior of this `read()` method of `StringIO` ?

Comment: `StringIO` is explicitly designed to be like a file. You have just finished writing to the "file," therefore the file pointer is at the end of the "file". So reading doesn't get anything, because you're at the end of the "file." That's why you have to `seek(0)` to read it. Because it's like a file. It works just like you'd expect it to work.

Comment: @armnotstrong: The second sentence in [the docs for StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) links to [the docs for file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects). There you'll find all the methods `StringIO` shares with file objects.

Comment: @unutbu +1 for the ```.seek(0)``` hint.  For me it was required to do ```Image.open(fake_file)``` with PIL