# after PIL.Image.tostring() "cannot identify image file"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, stringio

I want to use an `string` for storing image data.

Background: In some other parts of the code I load Images, which were downloaded from the web, and stored as `string` using

```
imgstr = urllib2.urlopen(imgurl).read()
PIL.Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imstr))
```

Now I do some image manipulations with an 'PIL.Image' object. I also want to convert these objects in the same `string`-format so that they can be used in the original code.

This is what I tried.

```
>>> import PIL
>>> import StringIO

>>> im = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (512, 512), "white")
>>> imstr=im.tostring()

>>> newim=PIL.Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imstr))
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2006, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

I found hints in the web, that this might happen. e.g [Python PIL: how to write PNG image to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string)
However I couldn't extract the correct solution for my sample code.

Next try was:

```
>>> imstr1 = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> im.save(imstr1,format='PNG')
>>> newim=PIL.Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imstr1))
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2006, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Comment: The `tostring()` method doesn't produce an image file format; it produces the *raw image data*. You can only load that again with `. What goal did you have in mind, save the image in a specific format to an in-memory file object?

Comment: If so you want [Python PIL: how to write PNG image to string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/646286)

Comment: Thank you for your extremly fast response. I have answered your questions, by editing my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to wrap the existing `StringIO` object in another such object; `imstr1` is *already* a file object. All you have to do is seek back to the start:

```
imstr1 = StringIO.StringIO()
im.save(imstr1, format='PNG')
imstr1.seek(0)
newim = PIL.Image.open(imstr1)
```

You can get the bytestring out of the `StringIO` object with the [`StringIO.getvalue()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO.getvalue):

```
imstr1 = StringIO.StringIO()
im.save(imstr1, format='PNG')
imagedata = imstr1.getvalue()
```

and then you can later load it back into a `PIL.Image` object in the opposite direction with:

```
newim = PIL.Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imagedata))
```

Comment: Thank you. This code is working. However I have to correct may question again. I found out that imstr should be a `string` object not a `StringIO` object. Kindly look at my edit above for more details.

Comment: @BerndGit: updated to show how to get the image data as a string.