# How to pass PIL image to Add_Picture in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-pptx

I'm trying to get the image from clipboard and I want to add that image in  python-pptx .
I don't want to save the image in the Disk. 
I have tried this:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from PIL import ImageGrab,Image
from pptx.util import Inches
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
left = top = Inches(1)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(im, left, top)
prs.save('PPT.pptx')
```

But Getting this error

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 627, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
import io
import PIL
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

# already have a PIL.Image as image
prs = Presentation()
blank_slide = prs.slide_layout[6]
left = top = Inches(0)

# I had this part in a loop so that I could put one generated image per slide
image: PIL.Image = MyFunctionToGetImage()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide)
with io.BytesIO() as output:
    image.save(output, format="GIF")
    pic = slides.add_slide(output, left, top)
# end loop
prs.save("my.pptx")
```

Comment: Should be: `pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(output, left, top)`

Answer (score 1):

The image needs to be in the form of a stream (i.e. logical file) object. So you need to "save" it to a memory file first, probably StringIO is what you're looking for.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string) provides some of the details.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an img as bytes, try this

```
    print(type(img)) #<class 'bytes'>       
    img_as_file = io.BytesIO()
    img_as_file.write(img)
    slide.shapes.add_picture(img_as_file,left,top)
```