# Open a 'PNG' file, then numpy, then base64, but image not shown?

Tags: python, image, numpy, pysimplegui

Try to do some image processing, load an image to show on Graph, but nothing shown.
Win10 / Python 3.7.6 / PySimpleGUI 4.16.0 / Numpy 1.18.1

I Load an image by PIL.Image, convert it to numpy array, then to base64, DrawImage in Graph, but show nothing. I had been work on it for serveral times and all OK. checked it for couple hours, but nothing help. Can someone help me to figure out where I missed or wrong ?

Something I found,

1. im open, im.show() OK
2. im.shape is correct, for example (200, 150, 3) for an 150 (width) x 200 (height) x RGB image.
3. im_np shown different data, it seems OK.
4. im_64 shown the byte string
5. draw is None, it should be a id.
6. with filename option set for DrawingImage, it is OK

I need to using numpy for some image process here, so conversion is required.

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image

filename = 'D:/Disk.png'
im = Image.open(filename)
width, height = im.size
im_np = np.array(im)    # It is necesary for future process
im_64 = base64.b64encode(im_np)

def Graph(key):
    return sg.Graph(im.size, graph_bottom_left=(0, 0),
                    graph_top_right=(width, height), key=key)

layout = [[Graph('GRAPH')]]
window = sg.Window('Graph', layout=layout, finalize=True)

draw = window.FindElement('GRAPH').DrawImage(
    data=im_64, location=(width/2, height/2))           # It failed
    # filename=filename, location=(width/2, height/2))  # It working well

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == None:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: Presumably you need to save the image after manipulating it, before passing it into `DrawImage`. I would suggest saving it to a `io.BytesIO` buffer. A quick look at the documentation shows `DrawImage` accepts `bytes` as the `data` argument. So use the `BytesIO.getvalue()` method. No need for base64 encoding.

Comment: `im_np = np.asarray(im); buffer = BytesIO(); np.save(buffer, im_np)` and set `data=buffer` in `DrawImage`, still not working. I had been tried it before post.

Comment: When you do `np.save(buffer, im_np)`, it isn't saving it in the `.png` image format. You need to use `PIL` to save it properly.

Comment: `im.save(buffer, format='PNG')` still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the PNG "as binary" encoded base64, not numpy array encoded as base64.

It's not so clear from [PySimpleGUI documentation](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but when passing `data` as base64, the data is not the raw data as base64, but the image file content as base64.

- Read PNG file as binary file:

  ```
  with open(filename, 'rb') as binary_file:
      #Read image file as binary data
      data = binary_file.read()
  ```
- Encode the binary representation as base64:

  ```
  im_64 = base64.b64encode(data)
  ```
- Pass `im_64` as `data`:

  ```
  draw = window.FindElement('GRAPH').DrawImage(
      data=im_64, location=(width/2, height/2))          # Works
  ```

---

Here is a code sample:

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image

#filename = 'D:/Disk.png'
filename = 'chelsea.png'

with open(filename, 'rb') as binary_file:
    #Read image file as binary data
    data = binary_file.read()

im = Image.open(filename)
width, height = im.size
im_np = np.array(im)    # It is necesary for future process
#im_64 = base64.b64encode(im_np)

# Encode the PNG binary representation 
im_64 = base64.b64encode(data)

def Graph(key):
    return sg.Graph(im.size, graph_bottom_left=(0, 0),
                    graph_top_right=(width, height), key=key)

layout = [[Graph('GRAPH')]]
window = sg.Window('Graph', layout=layout, finalize=True)

draw = window.FindElement('GRAPH').DrawImage(
    data=im_64, location=(width/2, height/2))          # Works
    #filename=filename, location=(width/2, height/2))  # It working well

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == None:
        break

window.close()
```

---

In case you want to display `im_np`, you may use the solution from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string).

- Write `im_np` as PNG image to string:

  ```
  im_pil = Image.fromarray(im_np)

  with io.BytesIO() as output:
      im_pil.save(output, format="PNG")
      data = output.getvalue()

  im_64 = base64.b64encode(data)
  ```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: The main reason to convert image array to base64 is to show the image after numpy processing. First solution is not necessary because I can use filename option directly in DrawImage. Second solution is what I need, but it may take some time for the conversion in animation. Anyway it's working, thank you for your reply.

Comment: You don't actually need to convert the data to base64, the following code also works: `draw = window.FindElement('GRAPH').DrawImage(data=data, location=(width/2, height/2))`