# How to store image in database using django models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have few questions please guide on these

1. I am try to stroe images in database but they are getting store in media directory
   2.The corresponding url is stored in  the db column but I need actual image to be stored in the
   db
   please advice

Comment: Why do you need to save images into the database? Best way to do: Though File System comes with some cost and certain cons, A good Internal Folder Structure and choosing a folder location which may be a little difficult to access by others.

Comment: if store images through filesystem , suppose system crash than we lose all the data

Comment: added in the answers you can check

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea to store an image in DB instead `media` folder. But you can use [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) for this:

**model.py**

```
class MyModel(model.Model):
    image = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
```

**view.py**

```
def image(request):
    image_file = request.FILES['image_file'].file.read()
    MyModel.objects.create(image=image_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to store the image itself in a database. You need to convert it to binary and store. You can use BytesIO. Here is a link which similar question explaining how to use it

[How to write PNG image to string with the PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/how-to-write-png-image-to-string-with-the-pil)