# What does cv2.imencode() do, and how do i achieve the same with PIL?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a rest API, and I came across this line of code-

```
_, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
```

What does this do? I unfortunately can't use OpenCV for m project, so is there any way I can achieve the same thing with PIL? Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Basically, cv2.imencode encodes an image to memory instead of writing the encoded image to an image file.

Comment: Use this answer and replace the png by jpg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/how-to-write-png-image-to-string-with-the-pil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It writes a JPEG-compressed image into a memory buffer (RAM) instead of to disk.

With PIL:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Create dummy red PIL Image
im = Image.new('RGB', (320,240), 'red')

# Create in-memory JPEG
buffer = BytesIO()
im.save(buffer, format="JPEG")

# Check first few bytes
JPEG = buffer.getvalue()
print(JPEG[:25])
```

Comment: Why is the JPEG being sliced? Hmm... So now let's say I want to post this image to my server, do I pass in Bufferm or JPEG?

Comment: As per the comment in the code, I only sliced and printed the first 25 bytes so you could see it looks like a regular JPEG without having to see thousands of pages of hex go past. You would pass `JPEG` to the server as it contains the entire image.

Comment: Its giving me this error :(
``` File "c:\Users\aadhi\Desktop\Code\Python\Scavenger Hunt\Server\test\client.py", line 21, in <module>
    image.save(buffer, format="JPG")
  File "C:\Users\aadhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2229, in save
    save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
KeyError: 'JPG'```

Comment: Changing format to JPEG seems to work!

Comment: Oh, sorry! I have updated the code - thanks for letting me know. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Oh no, it's fine! Thanks, again!