# Python / Pillow: treat an animated GIF or WEBP in place

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to resize a complete GIF (all frames) in place/in memory, without saving it to disk. I'm using Pillow/PIL. I've seen the other examples of "how to create or modify an animated GIF with Pillow", but the all use the Images's save method like this:  `first_frame.save("anim.gif", save_all=True, append_images=additional_frames)`. I cannot do it this way, for several reasons (or it would be a big overhead for my program).

Example (what I tried):

```
im = Image.open("my.gif")
for i in range(im.n_frames):
    im.seek(i)
    result = im.resize(new_width, new_height)
    im.paste(result)
print(im.size) >> old size
```

It looks like the `result` is not pasted?

I've also tried this: `im.paste(result, (0, 0, new_width, new_height))` to explicitly define how the resulting frame should be pasted, but this doesnt help as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at. You should be aware that the individual frames of a GIF may be different sizes... if the GIF is a picture of a man waving at you, the first image might be the whole man but the remainder may just be images of just his hand in different positions in order to save space in the GIF.

Comment: I want to know if I am missing something, and if it is really not possible to do it - treat all frames in memory, without saving the image with the save() method.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Just save the image into a `BytesIO` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70275120/2836621 It just writes the image to a memory buffer.

Comment: thanks - works! will gladly accept your answer, if you want.

Comment: It’s only a comment  really - not an answer. And it doesn’t seem right to duplicate the other answer so you can’t reallly upvote/accept here.